# Terraform - Best practice which files to add to Git?

Tags: terraform

After creating `main.tf` and executing `terraform apply`

The following files are created:

- terraform.tfstate
- .terraform/

Should I add these files to Git?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I commit .tfstate files to Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486335/should-i-commit-tfstate-files-to-git)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should add `.terraform` to your `.gitignore` file and never commit it.

`terraform.tfstate`, on the other hand, is something you'd want to preserve. The best way to do this is to use a remote backend, such as S3. Committing this to source control is a bad practice, but would still work and is definitely better than losing the state file.

Comment: Good answer. I approve.