# Terraform: How to migrate state between projects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

What is the least painful way to migrate state of resources from one project (i.e., move a module invocation) to another, particularly when using remote state storage? While refactoring is relatively straightforward within the same state file (i.e., take this resource and move it to a submodule or vice-versa), I don't see an alternative to JSON surgery for refactoring into different state files, particularly if we use remote (S3) state (i.e., take this submodule and move it to another project).

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The least painful way I’ve found is to pull both remote states local, move the modules/resources between the two, then push back up. Also remember, if you’re moving a module, *don’t* move the individual resources; move the whole module.

For example:

```
cd dirA
terraform state pull > ../dirA.tfstate

cd ../dirB
terraform state pull > ../dirB.tfstate

terraform state mv -state=../dirA.tfstate -state-out=../dirB.tfstate module.foo module.foo

terraform state push ../dirB.tfstate

# verify state was moved
terraform state list | grep foo

cd ../dirA
terraform state push ../dirA.tfstate
```

Unfortunately, [the `terraform state mv command` doesn’t support specifying two remote backends](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10481), so this is the easiest way I’ve found to move state between multiple remotes.

Comment: If you searching for entire resource address module.foo using grep then special characters can be escaped using `sed -e 's/[]\/$*.^[]/\\&/g'`

Comment: In Windows PowerShell, the redirect to file in the `state pull` command makes the state file have line endings not accepted by the `state mv`  command. Piping it to sc will work: `terraform state pull | sc ../dirB.tfstate`

Answer (score 13):

Probably the simplest option is to use `terraform import` on the resource in the new state file location and then `terraform state rm` in the old location.

Terraform does handle some automatic state migration when copying/moving the .terraform folder around but I've only used that when shifting the whole state file rather than part of it.

Comment: before `terraform state rm` is there a way to see what has to be imported from the existing statefile ?  e.g.  terraform import 'module.xyz' '??????'

Answer (score 8):

I use this script (not work from v0.12) to migrate the state while refactoring. Feel free to adopt it to your need.

```
src=<source dir>
dst=<target dir>
resources=(
    aws_s3_bucket.bucket1
    aws_iam_role.role2
    aws_iam_user.user1
    aws_s3_bucket.bucket2
    aws_iam_policy.policy2
)
cd $src
terraform state pull >/tmp/source.tfstate
cd $dst
terraform state pull >/tmp/target.tfstate
for resource in "${resources[@]}"; do
    terraform state mv -state=/tmp/source.tfstate -state-out=/tmp/target.tfstate "${resource}" "${resource}"
done
terraform state push /tmp/target.tfstate
cd $src
terraform state push /tmp/source.tfstate
```

Note that `terraform pull` is deprecated from v0.12 (but not removed and still works), and `terraform push` [does not work](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/terraform-enterprise.html) anymore from v0.12.

> Important: The terraform push command is deprecated, and only works
> with the legacy version of Terraform Enterprise. In the current
> version of Terraform Cloud, you can upload configurations using [the API. See the docs about API-driven runs](https://www.terraform.io/cloud-docs/run/api) for more details.

==================

Below are unrelated to the OP:

If you are renaming your resources in the same project.

- For version <= 1.0: use `terraform state mv ...`.
- For version >= 1.1, use the `moved` statement described: [here](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-1-1-improves-refactoring-and-the-cloud-cli-experience) or [here](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/refactoring#moved-block-syntax).

There are several other useful commands that I listed in [my blog](https://transang.me/11-useful-terraform-commands/)

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in a related Terraform Q -> [Best practices when using Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157516/best-practices-when-using-terraform/56820116#56820116)

> 1. It is easier and faster to work with smaller number of resources:
>
>    - Cmds`terraform plan` and `terraform` apply both make cloud API calls to verify the status of resources.
>    - If you have your entire infrastructure in a single composition this can take many minutes (even if you have several files in the same
>        folder).

So if you'll end up with a mono-dir with every resource, never is late to start segregating them by service, team, client, etc.

---

### Possible Procedures to migrate Terrform states between projects / services:

### Example Scenario:

Suppose we have a folder named `common` with all our `.tf` files for a certain project and we decided to divide (move) our `.tf` **Terraform** resources to a new project folder named `security`. so we now need to move some resources from `common` project folder to `security`.

#### Case 1:

If the `security` folder still does not exists (which is the best scenario).

1. Backup the Terraform backend state content stored in the corresponding AWS S3 Bucket (since it's versioned we should be even safer).
2. With your console placed in the origin folder, for our case `common` execute `make init` to be sure your `.terraform` local folder it's synced with your remote state.
3. If the `security` folder still does not exists (which should be true) clone (copy) the `common` folder with the destination name `security` and update the `config.tf` file inside this new cloned folder to point to the new S3 backend path (consider updating 1 account at a time starting with the less critical one and evaluate the results with `terraform state list`).

**eg:**

```
# Backend Config (partial)
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.11.14"

  backend "s3" {
    key = "account-name/security/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

4. Inside our newly created `security` folder, run `terraform-init` (without removing the copied `.terraform` local folder, which was already generated and synced in step 2) which, as a result, will generate a new copy of the resources state (interactively asking) in the new S3 path. This is a safe operation since we haven't removed the resources from the old `.tfstate` path file yet.

```
$ make init
terraform init -backend-config=../config/backend.config
Initializing modules...
- module.cloudtrail
- module.cloudtrail.cloudtrail_label

Initializing the backend...
Backend configuration changed!

Terraform has detected that the configuration specified for the backend
has changed. Terraform will now check for existing state in the backends.

Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
Do you want to copy existing state to the new backend?
  Pre-existing state was found while migrating the previous "s3" backend to the
  newly configured "s3" backend. No existing state was found in the newly
  configured "s3" backend. Do you want to copy this state to the new "s3"
  backend? Enter "yes" to copy and "no" to start with an empty state.

  Enter a value: yes
...                                                             

Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically                                                                        
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.                                                                                    

Initializing provider plugins...                                                                                                              
...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Terraform has been successfully initialized!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
...
```

[image]

5. Selectively remove the desired resources from each state (`terraform state rm module.foo`) in order to keep the desired ones in `/common` and `/security` paths. Moreover, It's a must to carry out in parallel the necessary updates (add/remove) of the modules/resources from your .tf files in each folder to keep both your local code base declaration and your remote `.tfstate` in sync. This is a sensible operation, please start by testing the procedure in the less critical possible single resource.

**As reference we can consider the following doc and tools:**

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/list.html
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/rm.html
- https://github.com/camptocamp/terraboard (apparently still not compatible with terraform 0.12)

#### Case 2:

If the `security` folder already exists and has it's associated remote .tfstate in its AWS S3 path you'll need to use a different sequence of steps and commands, possible the ones referenced in the links below:
1. https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/list.html
2. https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/pull.html
3. https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/mv.html
4. https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/push.html

**Ref links:**

- https://github.com/camptocamp/terraboard (apparently still not compatible with terraform 0.12)
- https://medium.com/@lynnlin827/moving-terraform-resources-states-from-one-remote-state-to-another-c76f8b76a996

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `terraform-state-split` cli which helps a lot with the process in big scale projects.

https://github.com/shebang-labs/terraform-state-split

Demo:
https://asciinema.org/a/qqF2E5Uz2ybwzhJdMpuufzblu

Install:

```bash
brew tap shebang-labs/tap
brew install terraform-state-split
```

Comment: As it is, this answer is just a link to some tool. A short example of how to use it would make it an acceptable answer.

Comment: The demo url was not good enough? I've listed instructions on how to install, a link to demo how to use it. But you have to spend sometime and read the documentation to cover your own use cases!

Comment: Link rot is real. If that demo link went dead tomorrow, would your answer be useful?

Comment: @RubberDuck Yes, because there's also the Github link.

Answer (score 0):

With terraform version 1.7+ you could solve this declaratively using [`removed`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/syntax#removing-resources) and [`import`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import) blocks, for resources that are importable.

```
# In source state:
removed {
  from = random_uuid.example

  lifecycle {
    destroy = false
  }
}

# In destination state:
import {
   to = random_uuid.example
   id = "aabbccdd-eeff-0011-2233-445566778899"
}
resource "random_uuid" "example" {}
```